# EJS content editable value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am have currently using express and mongoDB for back end and EJS for front end. My code is below. As you can see, I have a **content editable** and I want to grab the value after I clicked the modify button. Right now the value is from my mongoDB, but what I want to occur is when I change the contents of the content editable and then click the modify button, I want to send a request to my database. I can figure out the back end, but all I need to figure out is how when I click the button, I can get the new value that is in contenteditable. Any hints or ideas would be very much apprecitiated.

```
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div contenteditable="true">
              <a href="<%=shortURL.full%>"><%=shortURL.full%></a>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <a href="<%=shortURL.short%>"><%=shortURL.short%></a>
          </th>
          <th>
            <form action="/delete" method="POST">
              <!-- prettier-ignore -->
              <button type="submit" name = "button" value = <%=shortURL.short%>>Delete url</button>
              <h1></h1>
            </form>
          </th>
          <th>
            <form action="/delete" method="POST">
              <!-- prettier-ignore -->
              <button type="submit" name = "modify">Modify</button>
              <h1></h1>
            </form>
          </th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You can make a JavaScript `fetch` call from the client/browser JS - to send a request to the database server via the ExpressJS web server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate a little bit more? I'm not trying to access the database right now. All I want is when I change the content editable value and then pick up the current value after I click modify. The current default value is from the database with URL being the database. I'm not sure if its because I am not clear?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. When I send a post request, I know how to update my database. The problem is me trying to get the value on the inside so that I can actually update it to what it on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

Add an hidden input and on `submit` set its value to be the the innerText or innerHTML of the `contenteditable` element.

```js
function set_value() {
  document.getElementById("for-div1").value = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" contenteditable>i am editable</div>

<form onsubmit="set_value(); ">

  <!-- this should be hidden -->
  <input type="text" id="for-div1">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, this should work. However, I'm not sure if this is standard when using EJS and express? It just feels a bit off to define a function because all my other functions have request and response? I feel like this kind of defeats the purpose of using requests and responses?

Comment: Actually this is just client side and will work for any server.

Comment: Hmm, so what you wrote above, I should be able to define this in my controller file? I just want to keep my functions consistent. Right now, I have the format, where controllers is all the functions that has requests and responses. And a routes file that defines the routes and imports my controller files. Thank you so much!